# Can a clan member enter a war after it's started?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If a clan member leaves the clan during war prep and *stays* gone even after war starts, will he be able to return and participate in the war?

Answer (score 4):

Yes (assuming he was included in war before he left the clan) as long as he returns before the war ends he can participate in that war.

*Happy Clashing*